# AWK field contains number range

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to use `awk` to output lines from a semi-colon (`;`) delimited text file in which the third field contains a number from a certain range. e.g.

```
[root@example ~]# cat foo.csv
john doe; lawyer; section 4 stand 356; area 5
chris thomas; carpenter;  stand 289 section 2; area 5
tom sawyer; politician; stan 210 section 4; area 6
```

I want `awk` to give me all lines in which the third field contains a number between 200 and 300 regardless of the other text in the field.

Comment: What if you had `stand 4 section 200`? If the actual requirement is to find records in which `stand` is between 200 and 300, then an acceptable solution should look for that word.

Comment: Thank you for the solution guys! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regular expression, like this:

```
awk -F\; '$3 ~ /\y2[0-9][0-9]\y/' a.csv
```

A better version that allows you to simply pass the boundaries at the command line without changing the regular expression could look like the following:

(Since it is a more complex script I recommend to save it to a file)

*filter.awk*

```
BEGIN { FS=";" }

{
    # Split the 3rd field by sequences of non-numeric characters
    # and store the pieces in 'a'. 'a' will contain the numbers
    # of the 3rd field (plus an optional empty strings if $3 does
    # not start or end with a number)
    split($3, a, "[^0-9]+")

    # iterate through a and check if a number is within the range
    for(i in a){
        if(a!="" && a[i]>=low && a[i]<high){
            print
            next
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
awk -v high=300 -v low=200 -f filter.awk a.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

***grep*** alternative:

```
grep '^[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*\b2[0-9][0-9]\b' foo.csv
```

The output:

```
chris thomas; carpenter;  stand 289 section 2; area 5
tom sawyer; politician; stan 210 section 4; area 6
```

---

If `300` should be *inclusive* boundary you may use the following:

```
grep '^[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*\b\(2[0-9][0-9]\|300\)\b' foo.csv
```